# Different p-values in my statistical analysis

Tags: python, statistics

I am trying for the first time to run a statistical analysis in Python.  I am using the pingouin package. When running the pingouin.normality . However, the p-values seem to be different, although the test statistics are the same. I'm also a beginner in statistics, so I have no idea what's happening.

Output from Python: [image]

Output from SPSS: [image]

Thank you for your time and help

I've tried running statistical analysis on both python and SPSS, and expected to get the same results. However, the results were different.